# Hilt can't find Application class even after been annotated with @HiltAndroidApp

Tags: android-studio, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have an issue with Hilt, I keep getting the error in the image below:
[image]

As the error indicates adding the annotation `@HiltAndroidApp` to the AppController class. I have already done this and the class name has also been added to the manifest file. Also, all the activities and fragments classes where hilt injection is used have been annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`. I have tried to debug the issue for hours but to no avail. The crash happens when `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called in the `SignupActivity.kt` file. Below is what part of the file looks like:
[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: The way you write your model is wrong. `val model: UserViewModel by viewModels()` must be outside onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix, My project is a multi module project. I failed to add hilt dependency to the app module (though it was present in the commons module). Hence it could not @HiltAndroidApp Annotation